# SEO and canonical links

Tags: seo, canonical-url, iframe

I've a site `abc.com` where the content is being served from a frame hosted at `def.com`.

Since, the content is hosted at `def.com`, the microdata information is not available on `abc.com`.

Currently, I've added a canonical url to `abc.com` on `def.com`.

Should I instead add a canonical url to `def.com` on `abc.com` ?

I want to improve the rank and visibility of `abc.com`.

Comment: This won;t work. abc.com is iframing its conent. That's not search engine friendly at all. Also, you're creating a loop. `def.com` will suffer for it and lose it rankings. In your case abc.com is a lost cause no matter what you do.

Comment: so then I should focus on def.com. right? and redirect all links to it? would it help?

Comment: It is always better to focus on one site and not try and add domain names thinking it will help things- it won't. There is a boat-load of really really bad SEO advice out there that makes good guys like you think they have to do these silly tricks. You have content for one site? Then make it the best dang site on the planet for the topic or do the best you can. It can take a while for this to happen, but it is the only real way to compete- honestly and forthrightly. And the best SEO secret I can give is that you ***do*** have the power to be the best on the net.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically digging a hole with your setup right now.

To start, run your setup through webpagetest.org and you'll notice extra latency to produce the content since you're doing two separate DNS lookups. One for abc.com and one for def.com.

On top of that, you're basically splitting one webpage into two making the content rather fragmented at best. These problems alone will rank your page low or may not even be indexed at all.

I'll explain the fragmentation.

You say your def.com site has a frame pointing to abc.com. Then on def.com you have the following user readable contents:

```
"This is a story about a"
```

Then on abc.com domain, you have the following user readable contents:

```
"garden"
```

Put it together and you think you'd have a page that is supposed to contain:

```
"This is a story about a garden"
```

But search engines will actually see def.com as:

```
"This is a story about a"
```

That's what I mean. I am being super simple here, but you get the point.

**Here's what I suggest...**

Combine the information from the two domains to make one webpage on the domain you want the page to be served from (which should be abc.com since thats what the site you want to rank). That way, the loading time is drastically reduced, and search engines will then be able to see all of the content in one go. On top of that, you won't need to use canonical tags if you take my suggestion.

Then anyone who accesses def.com should receive a 301 status page with a redirection to abc.com where ALL the content should be. No IFrame is needed and no canonical tag is needed.